# <terminated> Usage: filename error

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Below is the correct code that should be able to run on Elipse. However i got the error message that says: " CreatedBibData [Java Application] Usage: CreateBibData filename".

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import oracle.xml.parser.v2.SAXParser;

public class CreateBibData extends HandlerBase {
  String elementEncountered;
  String journalName, journalCode, vol, num, 
         startPage, endPage, title; 
  String authorNames[];
  int numRows;
  int numAuthors;
  static public void main(String[] argv) {
    try {
      if (argv.length != 1) {
        // Must pass in the name of the XML file.
        System.err.println("Usage: CreateBibData filename");
        System.exit(1);
      }
      // Create a new handler for the parser
      CreateBibData createData = new CreateBibData();

      // Get an instance of the parser
      Parser parser = new SAXParser();

      // Set Handlers in the parser
      parser.setDocumentHandler(createData);
      parser.setErrorHandler(createData);

      // Convert file to URL and parse
      try {
        parser.parse(createURL(argv[0]).toString());
      } catch (SAXParseException e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (SAXException e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
  }

  public void startDocument() {
    System.out.println("--Start of SQL Insert Statements");
    authorNames = new String[20];
    numRows=0;
  }

  public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
    System.out.println("--End of SQL Insert Statements");
    System.out.println("Just generated "+numRows+
                       " SQL insert statements");
  }

  public void startElement(String name, AttributeList atts) 
                   throws SAXException {
    elementEncountered = name;
    if (name.equals("Authors")) {
      numAuthors=0;
    }
  }

  public void endElement(String name) throws SAXException {
    if (name.equals("Article")) {
      String aid=journalCode+":"+vol+":"+num+":"+startPage;
      System.out.println("insert into articles values ('"+ 
          aid +"','" + journalName+"',"+ vol+","+ num+","+
          startPage+","+ endPage+",'"+ title+"');");
      numRows++;
      for (int i=0; i<numAuthors; i++) {
        System.out.println("insert into authors values('"+
            aid+"','"+authorNames[i]+"');");
        numRows++;
      }
      numAuthors=0;
    }
  }

  public void characters(char[] cbuf, int start, int len) {
    if (elementEncountered.equals("JournalName")) {
      journalName = new String(cbuf,start,len);
      int ii = journalName.indexOf("(");
      int jj = journalName.indexOf(")");
      journalCode=journalName.substring(ii+1,jj);
    }
    else if (elementEncountered.equals("Volume")) {
      vol=new String(cbuf,start,len);
    }
    else if (elementEncountered.equals("Number")) {
      num=new String(cbuf,start,len);
    }
    else if (elementEncountered.equals("Title")) {
      title=new String(cbuf,start,len);
    }
    else if (elementEncountered.equals("StartPage")) {
      startPage=new String(cbuf,start,len);
    }
    else if (elementEncountered.equals("EndPage")) {
      endPage=new String(cbuf,start,len);
    }
    else if (elementEncountered.equals("Title")) {
      title=new String(cbuf,start,len);
    }
    else if (elementEncountered.equals("Author")) {
      authorNames[numAuthors++]=new String(cbuf,start,len);
    }
   elementEncountered = "";
  }

  public void warning (SAXParseException e)
              throws SAXException {
    System.out.println("Warning:"+e.getMessage());
  }

  public void error (SAXParseException e)
              throws SAXException {
    throw new SAXException(e.getMessage());
  }

  public void fatalError (SAXParseException e)
              throws SAXException {
    System.out.println("Fatal error");
    throw new SAXException(e.getMessage());
  }

  static URL createURL(String fileName) {
    URL url = null;
    try {
      url = new URL(fileName);
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        File f = new File(fileName);
        try {
          String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
          String fs = System.getProperty("file.separator");
          if (fs.length() == 1) {
            char sep = fs.charAt(0);
            if (sep != '/')
              path = path.replace(sep, '/');
            if (path.charAt(0) != '/')
              path = '/' + path;
          }
          path = "file://" + path;
          url = new URL(path);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot create url for: "+ 
                               fileName);
            System.exit(0);
          }
      }
    return url;
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Sounds like the code is not written by you. If you read the main() method, you will know that the program throws that error if you don't pass exactly one argument.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The code is not written by me and it throws an exception. How can I set up my environment right so that it does not throw this exception? Thanks.

Comment: I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Run->Run configurations* from the menu. Then enter the *full path* to the filename in the arguments box, and click the "Run" button. IF the file is at the root level of your project, you can simply give the filename too.

By doing this, you are sending the argument to your `main` method (Which takes a `String[]` as input).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In this program arguments, I think I should put in the xml file that is related to this program. However, I try the path, it still gives me the same exception message.

Comment: Can you create a screenshot of your Run configuration and upload to http://imgur.com/ ?

Comment: Looks fine, and you clicked the "Run" button on the same window? If the file is not present at that location, you should see a different error at least.

Comment: This is the error I got now: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\dd\workspace\SAXProcessing\bib.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Ok. So can you place the file in that location and re-run the program? Or you could place it elsewhere (like C:\) and give that full path in the arguments window.

Comment: When I rerun it with the path with C:xxxxx it gives me the same message as "CreatedBibData [Java Application] Usage: CreateBibData filename"."